# Tkinter Label Text Overlaps in Specific Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on a "simple" search interface using Python and Tkinter. Here is some example code of what I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

from tkinter import *
import os
import csv
import sys

def fetch()

    word = e1.get()
    definitions = []

    with open(file) as db:
        dbreader = csv.reader(db, delimiter="\t")
        for row in dbreader:
            if word in row[1]:
                definitions.append(row[4])

    if not definitions:
        output_string = word + " not in database"

    else:
        output_string = "Found " + word

    result_out = Label(master)
    result_out.config(text=output_string)
    result_out = result_out.grid(row=3, column = 0)

master = Tk()

word_entry = Label(master, text = "word")
word_entry.grid(row=0, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Search', command=fetch).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N, S, W, E), pady=4)

mainloop()
```

The code operates as intended if I am searching words that are found in the database. If I search a word that is not in the the database, my next search with a word that is present will overlap the previous output. The opposite is true, if I only search items not found in the database, the label refreshes as expected. When these loops "alternate" I experience issues. What in the world is going on?

Comment: Every time your event handler (`fetch`) runs you create a new label `result_out`.  You always put result_out into grid position 0, 3.  This stacks all these labels on top of one another.  That will be a mess and is almost certainly not what you want.  Since I can't run your code and you didn't explain what you want it to do, I can't tell you how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to load dafinitions from file every time you call `fetch()`? I think not. I have put definitions outside the function. Also, instead of loading definitions from a file I just define a set of random cheeses for testing purposes.

You create a new `result_out` label for every question, which @Paul Cornelius points out. It's better to assign a textvariable to the label and use it to change the text. So, create this label outside the function as well.

```
from tkinter import *

definitions = ['Stilton','Cheshire','Tilsit','Brie'] # Instead of file read

def fetch():
    word = e1.get()
    if not (word in definitions):
        output_string = word + " not in database"
    else:
        output_string = "Found " + word
    query.set(output_string) # Set result_out to output_string

master = Tk()

word_entry = Label(master, text = "word")
word_entry.grid(row=0, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

query = StringVar() # Use StringVar to interact with result_out
result_out = Label(master, textvariable=query)
result_out = result_out.grid(row=3, column = 0)

Button(master, text='Search', command=fetch).grid(row=2, column=1,
                                                  sticky=(N, S, W, E), pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Using the StringVar() and the result_out label outside the loop solved my issue. I'll mark resolved.