# Tkinter Creating Multiple Labels from Loop without Overlap

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is a follow up from this resolved question: [Tkinter Label Text Overlaps in Specific Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400306/tkinter-label-text-overlaps-in-specific-loop)

I'm trying to loop through a list and create clickable links:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

from tkinter import *
import os
import csv
import sys
import webbrowser

def callback(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(event.widget.cget("text"))

def fetch():
    #DO SOME STUFF
    #
    #
    for definition in definitions:
        url = "http://dictionary.com/browse/{0}".format(definition)
        link.set(url)

master = Tk()

link = StringVar()
word_entry = Label(master, text = "word")
word_entry.grid(row=0, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Search', command=fetch).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N, S, W, E), pady=4)

#TROUBLE AHEAD
lbl = Label(master, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
lbl.configure(textvariable=link, wraplength=500, justify = LEFT)
lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan = 60)
lbl.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
#END TROUBLE    

mainloop()
```

The main issue is the variable "link" will only be the last string in the list. I've read about using a "tracer" but haven't had any luck. Could I get a simplified version of what I'm trying to do? Ideally output would look like so:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/foo

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bar

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/baz

I should add I can get the desired output if I put the label creation in it's own subroutine but then there is overlap with each subsequent search.

Comment: You are creating the `lbl` before you set the `StringVar` to `url`. Create the `lbl` in the `fetch` function after you assign `url` to the StringVar.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look like what you are after?

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import webbrowser

definitions = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

def callback(event, url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

def fetch():
    for index, definition in enumerate(definitions):
        url = "http://dictionary.com/browse/{0}".format(definition)

        lbl = Label(master, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        lbl.configure(text=url, wraplength=500, justify = LEFT)
        lbl.grid(row=3+index, column=0, columnspan = 60)
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", partial(callback, url=url))

master = Tk()

word_entry = Label(master, text = "word")
word_entry.grid(row=0, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Search', command=fetch).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N, S, W, E), pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this does not solve the overwriting problem for subsequent searches. I may have not been entirely clear on that. If I search for a new "word" after a previous search, the url labels will overlap. This is why I was thinking the label needed to be created outside the fetch loop and use a text variable.

Comment: Thought as much. You did not explain in any detail how you would like your application to work, so I guessed and presented a mechanism by which it could be done. If you try to understand it you can use it. If you don't understand the principle then please explain specifics. Later you will perhaps stumble on to some other problem, then feel free to ask another question.